# Dagger2 How to make Injected Object know who created it

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

For example I have:

```
Public Class A extends Parent{
    @Inject B b;

    public A(){
     DaggerAppComponent.create().inject(this); //inject b here
    }

    public void doStuff(){
        b.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDone(){
       Log.v(TAG, "done");
    }
}
```

and in class B:

```
Public Class B{
    private Parent parent;

    Public B(Parent parent){
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public void start(){
       parent.onDone();
    }
}
```

My question is how can I pass the instance of class A to class B? In the dagger AppModule I have provide methods for both class A and class B:

```
@Module
Public AppModule{

    @Provide
    @Singleton
    A provideA(){
        return new A();
    }

    @Provide
    B provideB(A a){
        return new B(A a);
    }

}
```

With this code I get a circular dependency, resulting in a stack overflow error. When A is created, A tries to inject  B, and a new A is created when the provide method creates B...

What's the correct way of injecting this? Or should I avoid injection in this case?

**New Thoughts:**
Maybe I can save the created objected(a and b) in the dagger module, and when the provide method is called, return the saved instance instead of creating a new one. This should be the same as using @Singleton, but it appears to me that the constructor is still called when the provide method is called.(When the constructor of A is called, it creates the stack overflow problem.) And I'm also worrying that saving variables in dagger module is a bad practice.

Comment: `My question is how can I pass the instance of class A to class B?` - you do that here `return new B(A a);` However for some reason you want to inject `B` into `A` ? Remove any trace of `B` from `A`.

Comment: @Mark Thanks for the reply. Yes, ‘A' need to create an instance of 'B', and 'B' needs to know who created it, because there might be a 'C' that's also creating it. If I remove traces of 'B' from 'A', how do I call 'b.start()'? I need that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this "core principle of dependency injection: a class shouldn’t know anything about how it is injected." at https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html

Unless someone come up and tell me I'm wrong, I'm going to assume that the injected object shouldn't know its parent.